# Error when trying to use ruby gem- NameError (uninitialized constant RightScraper::Scraper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use a ruby gem called right_scraper. I have added the gem to my gem file and it installs fine. I used the example code from the gems github page (https://github.com/rightscale/right_scraper)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'right_scraper'

scraper = RightScraper::Scraper.new(:basedir => '/tmp', :kind => :cookbook)
scraper.scrape(:type => :git, :url => 'git://github.com/rightscale/right_scraper.git')
```

running this code returns the following error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant RightScraper::Scraper)
```

Does anyone know whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the README is out of date; that class does indeed not exist.

In cases like this, it is often a good idea to look at the `specs` to see what the correct usage should be. For example, based on [this spec](https://github.com/rightscale/right_scraper/blob/master/spec/git/scraper_spec.rb#L55), I found the following works:

```
RightScraper::Main.new(:basedir => '/tmp', :kind => :cookbook)
```

It would also be a good idea to raise this as an [issue](https://github.com/rightscale/right_scraper/issues) with the author. You could even provide a pull request with some up-to-date documentation.